# How can I populate a TextBox control with the date from a Calendar control?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, calendar

I can see the date population on the web page. However, it is not showing up in the `TextBox`. I need the calendar date selected to show up on the `TextBox`.

Below is my `Default.aspx` code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" %>

  <script runat="server">
      Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
          TextBox1.Focus()
      End Sub
      Protected Sub Calendar1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
          Response.Write("You selected: " &
            Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString())
      End Sub
  </script>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head id="Head1" runat="server">
       <title>Using the Calendar Control</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"
          OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged">
         </asp:Calendar>
      </div>
      </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Removed tags from title; noise reduction.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
Response.Write("You selected: " & Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString())
```

to:

```
TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: Racil Hilan, Thank you for your guidance. It resolved that issue.